# how do i show user posts in one page and at the same time users can see others posts in their page? like the way facebook works?

Tags: django

I am creating a website which has a homepage where all users can see others posts and i want to allow users see their own posts in their profile and see other peoples posts when they visit their profile how do i do that?

i have tried filtering the posts but the problem now is the logged in user is able to see his/her posts in his profile page but when he/she visits another user he sees hi own posts on that users page

this is my views

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Profile/Profile.html'
    #queryset = Posts.objects.all()



    @login_required
    def view_profile(self,request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            posts = User.posts.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            user = request.user
            #args = {'user': request.user}
            #if pk:

            posts = User.posts.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        return render(request,('Profile/Profile.html'), {'user': user , 'posts':posts  })


    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        #form = HomeForm()
        #posts = Post.objects.all().values('user') #order_by('-date')
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).order_by('-date')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        if pk:
            posts = Post.objects.get()#.order_by('-date')
            #user = User.posts.get(request, pk)
        else:
            user = request.user
        #friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        #friends = friend.users.all()

        args = { 'posts': posts, 'users': users,

        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

this is my profile.html

```
   {% for post in posts %}
   <div class="row" style="width: 18rem; height:18rem; display:table-row"  >
      <div class=" card border-grey row  mb-3 shadow border-bottom-0"   >
          <div class="card-header " >

           <!-- <a class="mr-auto " href="{% url 'Profile:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"> <b>{{ post.user.username }} </b> </a>-->

          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            {% if post.image %}
            <p class="card-text border-dark" > 

                <img src="{{ post.image.url  }}" class="mw-100 rounded border-dark" style="width: 20.24rem; ">

            </p>{% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer bg ">


          </div>

        </div>
        {% endfor  %}

  </div>
```

Comment: `posts = User.posts.objects.get(pk=pk)` doesn't make sense. You have a `user`, if you want the user's posts, then `posts = user.posts.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a method `view_profile` in the `ProfileView` class. This is never called. You can do two things:

- Create a different view when users are viewing someone else's profile: You can still use the same template, but it gives you the flexibility later on to add functionality to a user's own profile (like edit posts) which you don't need in the other view. Also it makes more sense since one the user's own profile page, you want to show the list of friends (other users) and maybe you don't want to show that when viewing the profile page of one of the friends. To do that, move `view_profile` into its own view with its own URL path.
- Or move the code you now have in `view_profile` to the `get` method. Just remember: when you have a `user` object (`user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)`), the list of posts is just `user.posts.all()`.

Comment: ok the reason i have method view_profile in the ProfileView is that I am passing user information through it (eg. name profile photo, email etc)and it is working fine. I tried to use the get method to pass user posts to the same template but now when a user visits another users profile, his posts are shown in all other users profile. is there a way I can pass users posts and his information in the view_profile in one method??and allow a user to see other peoples posts in their profile page?  I would really appreciate

Comment: Your `view_profile` method cannot be fine. It’s never called and it contains code that would raise exceptions. The only method that’s called is the `get` method.

Comment: I have deleted it(view_profile) and now all information is being passed through get method.  how do I allow a user to see posts on another users profilepage? and to see his own posts in his own profile page. There is a home page where all users posts are displayed @dirkgroten

Comment: more or less like you tried: if there's a `pk` it means he's viewing another user's profile page, so you fetch that other `user` and then `posts = user.posts.all()`. If there isn't a pk, then `posts = request.user.posts.all()`.

Comment: i changed pk=pk to user=user and it has worked perfectly good.